# How long google chrome and firefox cache DNS records

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns

For how long **Firefox** and **Chrome** cache **DNS** records in its own(browser) **DNS** cache ? Do they respect **TTL** ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think its a duplication of [Firefox invalidate dns cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063496/firefox-invalidate-dns-cache)

There are two configuration values for it in **Firefox**:
`network.dnsCacheExpiration` and `network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod` with a default of 60 seconds (v45).

More info: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration

In **Chrome**:
chrome://net-internals/#dns It seems the default is ~1minute (v66).

Don't forget about your system DNS cache. The browser does not talk with the DNS server directly, but rather your system resolver, so TTL is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Try also this solution, it uses the "hidden" top right black arrow in the chrome net-internals page.
It works immediately.

[Prevent Chrome from caching a site's DNS records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322046/prevent-chrome-from-caching-a-sites-dns-records/39124052#39124052)