# AWS Cloudsearch re-resolve DNS to IP regularly?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch, aws-sdk-js

In order to submit queries to CloudSearch dommain, the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/submitting-search-requests.html) says that "You should also re-resolve the endpoint DNS to an IP address regularly". But I cannot find a way to do that using AWS JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context in which you're using the SDK (eg, in-browser, NodeJS, ...),  you *probably* do not need to touch this.

DNS caching is fairly low-level stuff that is usually handled for you by whatever framework you're using. For example, if using NodeJS, the DNS Time-to-Live (TTL) can be configured like this
https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dnspromises_resolveany_hostname , whereas browsers maintain their own DNS caches (default to 60s for chrome and firefox) --  [How long google chrome and firefox cache DNS records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917513/how-long-google-chrome-and-firefox-cache-dns-records)

To be safe, I would just check the DNS cache TTL that applies to your specific implementation.